# Namespaced helper won't load in Laravel 4

Tags: namespaces, laravel-4, helper

I have a controller that calls a helper class in my app/helpers directory and then that helpers calls another class within it's namespace, but it can't find that class.

So here is my controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Controllers\Dash;

use \App\Models\SalesFlyer;
use \App\Helpers\MyPdf;

class FlyerBuilderController extends BaseController {

    public function getPdf($flyerId = null) {
        $flyer = new SalesFlyer();
        $flyerData = $flyer->getSalesFlyerName($flyerId);

        $flyerPath = public_path().'/assets/media/flyers/'.Session::get('userid').'/'.$flyerData->name.'-'.$flyerId.'.html';

        return MyPdf::downloadPdf($flyerPath, $flyerData->name);
    }
}
```

It catches MyPdf class perfectly fine. Here is MyPdf class:

```
<?php

namespace App\Helpers;

class MyPdf {

    public static function downloadPdf($filePath, $filename) {

        $client = new PdfCrowd("anthonythomas", "1ebd0d6e3ec1dfa83a6c5f3dd32906f0");

        // other code here
    }
}
```

The PdfCrowd class is within App\Helpers namespace like so:

```
<?php

namespace App\Helpers;

//
// Pdfcrowd API client.
// 
class PdfCrowd { }
```

> Class 'App\Helpers\PdfCrowd' not found

Here is my start/global.php file:

```
<?php

ClassLoader::addDirectories(array(

    app_path().'/commands',
    app_path().'/controllers',
    app_path().'/controllers/dash',
    app_path().'/controllers/dash/product',
    app_path().'/models/Product',
    app_path().'/models',
    app_path().'/database/seeds',
    app_path().'/helpers',

));
```

Then here is my composer:

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "app/commands",
        "app/controllers",
        "app/controllers/dash",
        "app/controllers/dash/product",
        "app/models",
        "app/models/Product",
        "app/helpers",
        "app/database/migrations",
        "app/database/seeds",
        "app/tests/TestCase.php"
    ]
}
```

Any idea why I'm getting that error?..

Answer (score 2):

Everything looks fine but you also have to remember to

```
composer dump-autoload
```

Every time you create a new class. Also, check the file

```
vendor/composer/autoload_classmap.php
```

You must see your Helper class there.

But if you use PSR-4, you can use the same namespace and you won't have execute `composer dump-autoload` again:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\Helpers\\": "app/helpers"
    }
},
```

Just remember to remove `"app/helpers",` from the classmap.

Comment: I do run composer dump-autoload.. And I added that psr-4 into my composer and deleted app/helpers from the classmap and still no luck.. it seems like it executes because it downloads the PDF and returns all the headers which are put out AFTER I call new PdfCrowd.. but it still throws that error. =(

Answer (score 0):

Ok for a shared hosting provider... EVERYTIME you add a new namespace and update composer even with psr-4 it seems, you have to replace the vendor directory with the current one on your local machine for it to actually go through! This saved me so much hours of time after I realized I had to replace the vendor directory everytime a composer dump-autoload was issued locally.